# How to make a UICollectionView to flip the entire page like a book

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to flip pages like a book, when you scroll from right to left, entire page flips to another page, but this page is a `UICollectionView`. How to do that? I am thinking using a `UIViewController` but the items on the page are like `UICollectionView` organized. It's better using `UICollectionView`, but when it comes to page flipper, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I also want to do the same. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flip entire page like a book, please visit the link:
http://code4app.net/category/ebook
It might going to help you in your work around.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `UIPageIvewController`. There you load other viewControllers into the single pages. And in these viewControllers you can easily implement `UICollectionView`